# Why does one of my HiFi speakers only start working after several minutes?

Tags: audio, fault

*not sure if this is an EE question, it's the closest SE site I could see?*

I have a Sony separates mini-system (HCD-SD1) I was given; it's quite old now but good. Except that for a while now, when I turn it on sound only comes through one speaker. After a few (~5) minutes the other speaker will kick in. Sometimes, whacking the volume right up to MAX seems to also remedy it but I prefer not to for obvious reasons.

It only happens when turning the device on and *seems* to be worse in colder weather so I think of it as the device "warming up" even though it's clearly solid state!

I already checked the cables aren't dodgy by swapping the speakers round - it's the same output that has the issue not the same speaker.

What could be the cause and is it something I might reasonably fix, or have fixed by someone more competent, without large expense? eBay suggests $50 (£30) or so would get me a replacement 2nd-hand unit.

[image]

Comment: Model? Picture (of the system and speakers)? With swapping speakers issue follows speaker, or remains with the channel?

Comment: Sorry - updated question

Comment: It's likely an dud electrolytic capacitor somewhere, possibly in the anti-pop circuit. Try finding a schematic or googling for known faults on this model. That's how I fixed both my mackie speakers.

Comment: When you connect headphones to the jack, do they exhibit the same issue?

Comment: @Anonymous no, I just checked and they are fine. Headphones also disable the speaker-out on this model, probably that's obvious.

Answer (score 3):

> no, I just checked and they are fine. Headphones also disable the speaker-out on this model, probably that's obvious

Ok, here's the [service manual](http://www.minidisc.org/manuals/sony/service/hcdsd1_11.pdf) with circuit diagrams. Power amps at pages 39-40 originate audio, forking to SPL/SPR for speakers, and HPL/HPR for headphones. As headphones sound ok for you, the issue is somewhere further that circuit: connector I, relay RY501 and its driving circuit built on Q501-Q503. However as you said one channel works properly, and another with delay, I would question the relay itself first and its contacts. If relay driving circuit would be an issue then both channels would behave the same. Probably relay gets warm as it starts operating properly with one of its contact pair. Relay part number is [1-515-920-11](https://www.qservice.tv/vpasp/shopexd.asp?id=14194), not sure if it is serviceable, but you may be able to gently tap it when there's no sound in one channel to see if it changes the situation. Also not clear if relay's contacts are normally open (however it is stated so in circuit and on the PCB in the manual).

Comment: I'll have to check before I mark as accepted but thankyou for the very thorough answer. For a novice, who has done small circuits and a little bit of soldering mostly in school, is this too ambitious a project in your opinion?

Comment: No, it should not be hard. What you need is being careful in assembling/disassembling, and finding the replacement part(s) when you will diagnose them.